# Run functions in list except for function specified

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to run a list of functions in a method from another method while skipping over 1 specified function in the list?

For example, I have the contentList method:

```
def contentList(self):  
    methods = [self.title, self.containerDIV, self.heading, self.stopSection, self.offlineSection, self.onlineSection, self.endDIV, self.otherImages]
    for m in methods:
        m()
def test(self):
    self.contentList()
    # skip over stopSection
```

Is there a way to run those methods from test method while skipping over or not running the self.stopSection?

**UPDATE**

Here is more on what I am trying:

```
#**************************** BEGIN OF HTML CONTENT ****************************

    def title(self):
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<div id='title'><img src='../images/title.png'></div>", "utf8"))

    def containerDIV(self):
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<div id='container'", "utf8"))

    def endDIV(self):
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</div>", "utf8"))

#**************************** END OF HTML CONTENT ****************************

    def contentList(self, skip_name):  # All content functions in list 
        methods = [self.title, self.containerDIV, self.endDIV]
        for m in methods:
            if m.__name__ != skip_name:
                m()


    def narrow(self):
        try:
            self.contentList('title')   # removed title
            return          

    # GET
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            self.contentList('none')  # I added none here because I want to keep title
            return
```

Comment: How are you specifying it? By position in the list? Or by identity? Both are possible, but the identity one might be tricky with methods.

Comment: It could be any of them.  I'm running contentList from many different methods and depending on the situation, I may need to skip over one of them that I don't want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check the function name by it's `__name__` attribute. So, in your case, you could do something like:

```
class SomeClass:
    def contentList(self, skip_method_name):  
        methods = [self.title, self.containerDIV, self.heading, self.stopSection, self.offlineSection, self.onlineSection, self.endDIV, self.otherImages]
        for m in methods:
            if m.__name__ != skip_method_name:
                m()

    def test(self):
        self.contentList('stopSection')
```

Let me provide a more concise example

```
class SomeClass:
    def method_a(self):
        print('method_a')

    def method_b(self):
        print('method_b')

    def method_runner(self, skip_name):
        for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b]:
            if m.__name__ != skip_name:
                m()
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> some_obj = SomeClass()
>>> some_obj.method_runner('')
method_a
method_b
>>> some_obj.method_runner('method_a')
method_b
>>> some_obj.method_runner('method_b')
method_a
```

As @Jeronimo pointed out, we may use the actual function in the `method_runner` method and bypass the `__name__` call at all. Using this aproach my example looks like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    def method_a(self):
        print('method_a')

    def method_b(self):
        print('method_b')

    def method_runner(self, skip_method):
        for m in [self.method_a, self.method_b]:
            if m != skip_method:
                m()
```

A sample usage:

```
>>> some_obj = SomeClass()
>>> some_obj.method_runner(None)
method_a
method_b
>>> some_obj.method_runner(some_obj.method_a)
method_b
>>> some_obj.method_runner(some_obj.method_b)
method_a
```

Comment: Works!  One more thing, when I try and call self.contentList() in other methods where I need all of the list to run, I get a type error that asks for 1 positional argument in the self.contentList().  I tested it by writing self.contentList(none) in my other method and it worked.  Is this best practice for this though?

Comment: The first argument of instance methods is a reference e to the object to which it is bound. It is, however implicit when you call it. Instead of adding none as the first argument add self on the function definition.

Comment: Why not just pass the function directly as an argument and check if it's this one in the loop?

Comment: @ bla sorry, where would I add self exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I'm kinda sleepy. It's very late here. I misunderstood your problem in the previous response. Could you show me some more of your code so I may reproduce this behavior? Btw, I hadn't thought about it @Jeronimo. I will include it on my answer first thing in the morning. :)

Comment: Oh, I just realized. You are trying to call `self.contentList` without the argument we just added. See that, in my example I passed an empty string so that no method is skipped. You may avoid this error by making `skip_method_name` an optional argument by giving it a default value something like `def contentList(self, skip_method_name='')`.

Comment: I added some stuff up top.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your scope you can temporary change the definition of the function before it executes.

**Global Scope**

```
    def t1():
        print('t1')

    def t2():
        print('t2')

    def contentList():
        methods = [t1, t2]
        for m in methods:
            m()
    def test():
        global t1
        def fake(): pass

        temp = t1
        t1 = fake
        contentList()
        t1 = temp

    test()
```

**Class Scope**

```
def test(self):
    def fake(): pass
    temp = self.stopSection
    self.stopSection = fake
    self.contentList()
    self.stopSection = temp
```